# How to get top 5 higher values in json files inside folder

Tags: php

```
 public function onRun(int $currentTick){
    foreach (glob($this->plugin->getDataFolder()."/players/*.json") as $plData) {
        $str = file_get_contents($plData);
        $json = json_decode($str, true);
        $levels = $json["level"];
       }
}
```

I want to get top 5 higher values from all json files in "players" folder, I only know how to get that value from all files, but don't know how to select 5 higher. Can someone help please?

EDIT: Json file looks like this:

```
{
"coins": 0,
"rank": "Guest",
"accept_friends": true,
"reward_time": 1440,
"level": "29",
"bio": "Today is very cool!c",
"progress": 24.939999999999998,
"local_ip": "10.0.0.1",
"registred": true,
"logged": true
```

}

Comment: Show an example of the `$json` array.

Comment: Ok, I edited post you can see it here

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: what's the status of this question? You neither accepted an answer if it solved the question nor commented under them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `usort`!

Make a function that will handle your sorting:

```
function levelSort($a, $b)
{
   return $a['level']>$b['level'];
}
```

next store your players to array, sort it and return first five elements:

```
 public function onRun(int $currentTick){
 $players = [];     // declare aray with proper scope
    foreach (glob($this->plugin->getDataFolder()."/players/*.json") as $plData) {
        $str = file_get_contents($plData);
        $json = json_decode($str, true);
        $players[] = $json;    // save to array
       }
 usort($players, 'levelSort'); // sort using custom function
 return array_slice($players, 0, 5); // return 5 elements

}
```

Should work. didn't tested tho :D

Of course this example assuming that every `$json` is an array and `$json['level']` exists and is int

Answer (score 0):

You need to build an array of `level`s with `$levels[]` as you are overwriting `$levels` each time.  Then just reverse sort and slice the top 5:

```
public function onRun(int $currentTick){
    foreach (glob($this->plugin->getDataFolder()."/players/*.json") as $plData) {
        $str = file_get_contents($plData);
        $json = json_decode($str, true);
        $levels[] = $json["level"];
    }
    rsort($levels);
    return array_slice($levels, 0, 5);
}
```

If you want to return the entire top 5 arrays:

```
public function onRun(int $currentTick){
    foreach (glob($this->plugin->getDataFolder()."/players/*.json") as $plData) {
        $str = file_get_contents($plData);
        $results[] = json_decode($str, true);
    }
    array_multisort(array_column($results, 'level'), SORT_DESC, $results);
    return array_slice($results, 0, 5);
}
```

Why are you passing in an argument `$currentTick` and not using it?  Maybe replace 5 with `$currentTick` so you can pass it in?